# Powershell get all varibles that equals false

Tags: powershell

I got a script that checks for a file and if found sets the variable $true, in the end of the script I'm trying to print what variables equal false and I can't make it work I tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
Get-Variable | Where-Object Value -like $false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `Get-Variable`'s results to `where-object` and check for value and type. If the check omits type, results are a bit surprising. Like so,

```
$foo = $true
$bar = $false

Get-Variable | ? { $_.value -eq $false  }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
bar                            False
DebugPreference                SilentlyContinue
false                          False
InformationPreference          SilentlyContinue
NestedPromptLevel              0
VerbosePreference              SilentlyContinue
WhatIfPreference               False

# Add type check too
Get-Variable | ? { $_.value -eq $false -and $_.value -is [boolean] }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
bar                            False
false                          False
WhatIfPreference               False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!, only 1 issue left, is there a way to filter the result to show only variables I declared?

Comment: @BugsBunny Kinda, but that would be a posted as a new question. SO's model is to create a set of distinct questions and answers. Broadening the scope is confusing for others who read the question later without knowing its history.

Comment: Gotcha, will mark this as answered and open a new question